# Concatenation not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and hence I can't use the `CONCAT` function. I want to concatenate three columns which have numbers in them with the datatype `nvarchar`.

I tried below two methods and they are not working for me:

```
select top 10 
    shoppingcartno + lineitemNo + POnumber 
from 
    tbSupplierLineItem

select top 10 
    CONVERT(varchar(30), ShoppingCartNo) +
    CONVERT(varchar(30), lineitemNo) +
    CONVERT(varchar(30), POnumber) 
from 
    tbSupplierLineItem
```

This is the sample data:

```
ShoppingCartNo  LineItemNo  DunsNo
--------------------------------------
1000105517      1           009122532
1000427144      2           099441680
1000427144      3           099441680
1000427144      4           099441680
1000491452      3           014296052
1000495759      3           825067460
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  The second should work (although you should use `nvarchar()` rather than `varchar()` based on the types of the strings.

Comment: Be aware that `'something' + null = null`

Comment: `POnumber` is not in your sample data. Is it supposed to be `DunsNo` ?

Comment: I got it. PO Number is NULL in my case. Thanks @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try altering the query like below

```
select top 10 
CONVERT(varchar(30),isnull(ShoppingCartNo,''))
+CONVERT(varchar(30),isnull(lineitemNo,''))
+CONVERT(varchar(30),isnull(POnumber,'')) 
from tbSupplierLineItem
```